# How to create this type of form in PHP

Tags: php, forms, email

I have to put a sort of "double opt-in newsletter registration form" in a website.

Since I don't know much about php, I thought about how to limit the code I have to write, and I thought this:

I want to create a registration form (with fields: name, email address and an OBLIGATORY checkbox); when the user clicks Submit:

1. Of course it checks that all the fields are filled in.
2. An email is sent to that email address.
3. User RESPONDS to that email, I see the reply on my email and I manually add him to my mailing list.

Is this a reasonable thing? If so, how do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add some steps to make it automatic, you don't have to do it manually

1. Of course it checks that all the fields are filled in.
2. An email is sent to that email address. with a unique link with some random key

   link `http://domain.com/confirm.php?regId=4&key=DTSRROymc90JDklrTu2wi64Nny0`
3. User RESPONDS to that email by `clicking` on confirm link in email,
4. You get the response from `confirm.php?regId=4&key=DTSRROymc90JDklrTu2wi64Nny0` and update its status to `confirm`if its found in db using `regId=4` and `key=DTSRROymc90JDklrTu2wi64Nny0`

in confirm.php

```
if(isset($_GET['regId']) && isset($_GET['key'])) {

   //Get the reg details and update the status if row found in db
   .... 

}
```

**[Here is an script](http://www.sendblaster.com/en/support/lists-importing/double-opt-free-php-form-mail), give it a try**

Comment: I know it normally works like this, but isn't it more complicated to write?

Comment: its not complicated, its simple because user is already authenticated if he/she can access that confirmation email.

Comment: @Bonno give it a try or you'll never find out.

Comment: update answer with a script link, check it might give you right direction